# Cвоя программа оценок

Tags: java

У меня есть вот такая небольшая программка:
1) Правильно ли написан код? 
2) Когда человек вводит строки, то выдаётся сообщение : "Введите цифры, зачем вы вводите строки?" и программа заканчивает свою работу. 
Как мне сделать программу, чтобы человек вводил строки, а программа выдала сообщение, но работала дальше, чтобы пользователь если ввёл строки, он получил сообщение и затем мог ввести числа, чтобы программа не "падала"

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            int mark = scanner.nextInt();
            if (mark >= 90) {
                System.out.println("Ваша оценка A, больше или ровно 90 баллам: " );
            }else if (mark >=80 && mark<90){
                System.out.println("Ваша оценка B, больше или ровно 80 баллам");
            }else if (mark >=60 && mark<80){
                System.out.println("Вы провалили тестирование");
            }
        }catch (InputMismatchException e){
            System.out.println("Введите цифры, зачем вы вводите строки?");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {  
  try {
    int mark = scanner.nextInt();
    if (mark >= 90) {
      System.out.println("Ваша оценка A, больше или ровно 90 баллам: " );
    } else if (mark >=80 && mark<90) {
      System.out.println("Ваша оценка B, больше или ровно 80 баллам");
    } else if (mark >=60 && mark<80) {
      System.out.println("Вы провалили тестирование");
    }
    break;
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Введите цифры, зачем вы вводите строки?");
    scanner.next();
  }
}
```

---

> зачем scanner.next()?

Если `scanner.nextInt();` приводит к исключению, `scanner` не двигается вперед по введенному тексту, а остается на том же месте. Надо прочитать то, что ввел пользователь, чтобы дать ему возможность ввести что-то еще.

Comment: Так если я ввёл строки, то должен выдать 1 сообщение: Введите цифры, зачем вы вводите строки? А потом я мог ввести цифры и всё норм бы отработало, а в коде если ввёдешь строки, то бесконечно выдается сообщение: Введите цифры, зачем вы вводите строки?

Comment: Можете объяснить зачем scanner.next()? Как я знаю он считывает до пробела, а в этой программе не понимаю как отрабатывает